# QList<QString> operator<<

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qlist, no-match

I have a QList element named competence inside a class, and another class object named k. I want to make a deep copy( this.competence must be a deep copy of k.competence ).
I use an iterator it:

```
QList< QString>::iterator it;
for(  it = k.competence->begin(); it != k.competence->end(); ++it )
{
    this.competence << (*it) ;
}
```

I got an error "no match for operator<<".
The problem is whenever I try this out of a loop:

```
QList< QString>::iterator it;
it = k.competence->begin();
this.competence << *it;
```

it doesn't give errors.

**EDIT: RESOLVED using QList.append() method instead of operator<<**

Comment: Sorry but this does not make much sense, if competence is an item of the list how can you iterate over an item ? you should iterate over the list in the meantime why you do not take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800206/how-to-deep-copy-qmap-and-other-qt-containers

Comment: Please, always include the exact verbatim error the compiler gives you.

Comment: Thanks all guys! You were really helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont get your use case here, you can do a shallow copy of a QList just by copying it. If you further modify the shared instance, a deep copy will be created.

```
QList newList(oldList);
```

If you want to do it your way, you need to append the iterator to your new list

```
QList newList;
for(QList< QString>::iterator it = oldList->begin(); it != oldList->end(); it++ )
{
    newList.append(*it) ;
}
```

Comment: I got that! Thanks! I used the operator<< to append items, but found out it was a mistake. append() method works fine.